# setup mail on centos

Tags: centos, email

When I try to send mail on CentOS:

```
mail -s "hello" root
```

> to=root, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00\ , xdelay=00:00:00,
>   mailer=relay, pri=30031, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=4.0.0,
>   stat=Deferred: Connection refused by [127.0.0.1]

My question is:

Do I need to setup an SMTP mail server on localhost for mail to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  There are plenty of HOWTOs on configuring sendmail, but iirc CentOS comes out of the box ready to run a working sendmail (for sending) on localhost.  Try

```
chkconfig --list sendmail
```

and if it's not running,

```
chkconfig sendmail on
service sendmail start
```

and try again.